# exception thrown while passing parameters

Tags: c++, segment-tree

I am getting error `Exception thrown at 0x009523B9 in Project5.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00E42ED4).`

in  the below program

test case:

> 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 1
>
> Q 2 4

I was getting error when executing this line 
`struct node query(int index, int start, int endv, int l, int r)`
that is when `query` function was called for first time in main

The parameter were like at the time of exception thrown should be
`query(0,0,4,1,3)`

but they are automatically changing to  `query(0,1,1,1,3)`
where I am doing wrong

This was the question based on segment trees [spoj KGSS](https://www.spoj.com/problems/KGSS/)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<climits>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)    //disable scanf warning 
using namespace std;

struct node {
    long long int maxsum;
    long long int maxnum;
};
long long int a[100];
struct node tree[100];
void build(int index, int start, int endv) {
    if (start == endv) {
        tree[index].maxsum = a[start];
        tree[index].maxnum = a[start];
    }
    else {
        int mid = (start + endv) / 2;
        build(2 * index + 1, start, mid);
        build(2 * index + 2, mid + 1, endv);

        tree[index].maxnum = max(tree[2 * index + 1].maxnum, tree[2 * index + 2].maxnum);
        tree[index].maxsum = max(tree[2 * index + 1].maxnum + tree[2 * index + 2].maxnum, max(tree[2 * index + 1].maxsum, tree[2 * index + 2].maxsum));
    }
}

struct node query(int index, int start, int endv, int l, int r) {

    struct node result;

    result.maxnum = INT_MIN;
    result.maxsum = INT_MIN;

    if (l > endv || r < start)
        return result;
    int mid = (start + endv) / 2;
    struct node left, right;
    left = query(index, start, mid, l, r);
    right = query(index, mid + 1, endv, l, r);

    tree[index].maxnum = max(left.maxnum, right.maxnum);
    tree[index].maxsum = max(left.maxnum + right.maxnum, max(left.maxsum, right.maxsum));

    return tree[index];
}

void update(int index, int start, int endv, int aidx, long long int value) {


    if (start == endv) {
        a[aidx] = value;
        tree[index].maxsum = value;
        tree[index].maxnum = value;
    }
    else {

        int mid = (start + endv) / 2;
        if (aidx <= mid) {
            update(2 * index + 1, start, mid, aidx, value);
        }
        else {
            update(2 * index + 2, mid + 1, endv, aidx, value);
        }

        tree[index].maxnum = max(tree[2 * index + 1].maxnum, tree[2 * index + 2].maxnum);
        tree[index].maxsum = max(tree[2 * index + 1].maxnum + tree[2 * index + 2].maxnum, max(tree[2 * index + 1].maxsum, tree[2 * index + 2].maxsum));
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    build(0, 0, n - 1);
    //for(int i = 0)
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int l, r;
        char ap;
        cin >> ap >> l >> r;
        if (ap == 'U') {
            update(0, 0, n - 1, l - 1, r);
        }
        else {
            struct node temp = query(0, 0, n - 1, l - 1, r - 1);
            printf("%lld\n", temp.maxsum);
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE -> I used `result.maxnum = INT_MIN;
                result.maxsum = INT_MIN;`

in query function and `result.maxnum` and `result.maxsum` are of `long long int` types and i am assigning `INT_MIN` to them.

This is because some times from both side of the recursion i get min value and on 
adding these values and storing them on a `int` variable leads to integer overflow thats why i used `long long int` can someone provide way for handling this situation or this is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

is incorrect when the type of `a[i]` is `long long int`. It's also not a good idea to mix C++ I/O with C I/o. There's nothing wrong with

```
cin >> a[i];
```

But the main problem is that you have a stack overflow. In your example

```
query(0,0,4,1,3) ->
 query(0,0,2,1,3) ->
  query(0,0,1,1,3) ->
   query(0,0,0,1,3) ->
    return result
   query(0,1,1,1,3) ->
    query(0,1,1,1,3) ->
     query(0,1,1,1,3) ->
      query(0,1,1,1,3) ->
       query(0,1,1,1,3) ->
        query(0,1,1,1,3) ->
         query(0,1,1,1,3) ->
          BOOM!! stack overflow
```

Not quite sure what to do to fix it, since I don't understand the code. I would have thought something like

```
if (start >= endv)
    return result;
```

at the beginning would help but I'm not really sure.

Comment: _"Not quite sure what to do to fix it"_ The obvious solution is to use a `std::stack` with an appropriate structure to represent the parameters. Any recursion can be replaced that way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But then you'd just replace the stack overflow with memory exhaustion. My point was that the algorithm needs to change because it's infinitely recursive, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: There's many more dynamic memory available than on the stack. If there's a proper condition to stop the recursion at all, `std::stack` would bring you far further.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The point (my point) is that there isn't a proper condition at the moment. Until that's corrected using `std::stack` is not a solution.

Comment: But My program terminates to the first call to `query()` I noted that while debugging ,how compiler is sure itself  that recursion will go infinitely without executing the full code

Comment: @akacoders I think you're mistaken. When I tested your program it terminated with a stack overflow when the variables had the values that you said they 'automatically' changing to. They're not automatically changing, they changing because of recursive calls.